# Adding TField and TDataset to Component Propertis

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I want to add two properties to my component: a TDataSet and a TField, so that when I set the TDataset property I can then select from its fields in the DataField Property.
I don't know how to make the relation between the DataField and the DataSet properties.

How can I do that?

Comment: I have edited your question to clean it up a little (why all the capitals?) but I still don't understand it. Can you [edit] it further? Maybe explain *why* you want to do this?

Comment: Are you creating custom data-aware component which should be reading or storing the data from or to database?

Comment: I just want to crate a component same as TDBLookup ComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your component to have a `DataSource: TDataSource` property instead of a `DataSet: TDataSet` property, Delphi's standard `TDataFieldProperty` editor will automatically populate your `DataField: string` property for you.  You can then link your desired `TDataSet` component to a `TDataSource` component.

If you want the drop-down list to appear for any `string` property that is not named `DataField`, you can register `TDataFieldProperty` manually for that property via `RegisterPropertyEditor()`.

If you want to have a `TDataSource` property whose name is not `DataSource`, you can derive from `TDataFieldProperty` and override its virtual `GetDataSourcePropName()` method.

If you must accept a `TDataSet` directly, you will have to write a custom property editor for your `DataField` property, and have it call `TDataSet.GetFieldNames()` directly.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy , your answer is very use full thanks

Comment: Hi Remy  I need more than one datafield  and I try to use RegisterPropertyEditor() but compiler raise error.  would you please more explain about  RegisterPropertyEditor()

Comment: What error are you seeing? What does your code look like?  Did you create a design-time package for your component to do this registration? Please edit your question to add these details.